# Are static members of a class template implicitly instantiated, or not?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

Consider the following two quotes:

> `[C++11: 14.7.1/1]:` *[..]* **The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of** the declarations, but not of the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, **static data members** and member templates; *[..]*
>
> `[C++11: 14.7.1/8]:` **The implicit instantiation of a class template does not cause any static data members of that class to be implicitly instantiated.**

(also found verbatim — except for a new reference to exception-specifications — in `[C++14: 14.7.1/1]` and `[C++14: 14.7.1/9]`, respectively)

What am I missing here? What is the difference between implicitly instantiating a class template and implicitly instantiating a class template specialization? How do these two quotes not conflict?

> `[C++11: 14.7.1/5]:` A class template specialization is implicitly instantiated if the class type is used in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or if the completeness of the class type might affect the semantics of the program. *[..]*

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, they don't sound like they conflict. The first quote reads: "...  causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, **but not of**...  static data members". The second quote says this as well.

Comment: @Cyber: I think you're misreading. That would be a very strange sentence structure that doesn't really make any sense: "the declarations" of _what_? Rather, I think the first quote says the declarations (but not definitions) of <all these things> are implicitly instantiated. The second quote says <one of these things> is not implicitly instantiated. The simplest solution is what Angew said: the second quote is missing the qualifier "definition of". But it's just that, it's missing, so for now the quotes conflict.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought the "but not of" applied to the rest of the statement, but after re-reading that couldn't be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the quotes are actually in conflict. Par. 1 says that the declaration of the static member is instantiated, bu the definition is not. Par. 8 says the member is not instantiated. Since a non-defining declaration of something is not really that *something,* I'd say they say the same thing. Par. 8 could just perhaps be clarified to include the word "definition" as well.

Here are a few quotes which I believe *support* my reasoning about Par.8 (even though none of them is a crystal-clear proof, unfortunately):

> **14.7/2** ... A member function, a member class, a member enumeration,
>   or a **static data member** of a class template instantiated from the **member definition** of the class template
>   is called, respectively, an instantiated member function, member class, member enumeration, or **static data
>   member**. ...
>
> **14.7.1/2** Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly
>   specialized, the **specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated** when the specialization is referenced
>   in a context that requires the member **definition** to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any associated
>   side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way
>   that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

(All taken from C++11, emphasis mine)

To me, these imply that "instantiating a static data member" really means "instantiating the **definition** of a static data member."

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Can you back up your claim with any prior research or some mailing list discussion or a DR or something? Not that I've been able to find any -.-

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not really, it's just how I parse the english text. "instantiate `(Dec && !(Def || DefArg))` of (mf, mc, sme, **sdm**, mt).

Comment: Oh, no, that part, para 1, is clear I think. I'm talking about para 8. While I agree with your interpretation of it, there's nothing in _that_ paragraph's text to actually prove it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Added a few quotes which I believe to support my interpretation.

Comment: Mmmm seems a bit thin :P I'm not sure you can just pick a paragraph, bold out every occurance of the phrases "static data member" and "definition" (no matter where they fall) and call it a day :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I also bolded out "definition" :-) I agree it's not clear-cut, but I do believe it supports the notion of "'instantiating X' means 'instantiating the definition of X'", which is what I am trying to prove to make sense of 14.7.1/8.